# sql performance using correlated sub-query to parent query vs over/partition by method for getting most recent record

Tags: sql-server-2008, correlated-subquery, partition-by

When I previously searched for the best way to find the most recent result for a given criteria field I came upon the method of using **over** (**partition by** criteria field order by sort field) which works well. Today after handing someone to make some changes to an old query I got back the reworked query and he used the parent field in a subquery as the criteria. I quickly googled and found this is a valid approach and admit that in many years of using SQL (by no means high level DBA here), I didn't know this was possible. Now my question is why isn't this method the one that comes up as it seems easier than the over/partition by method? I can guess that the over/partition by allows for greater flexibility in the way things are sorted but for simple latest/earliest/lowest/highest this would seem to be a better way to go. The other question what is the performance difference between the 2 over larger data sets, is one better than the other?

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled ok valid, but what about the other things, is over/partition more robust? Was the way I was searching the reason why I didn't come across correlated-query approach for the solution to finding latest results?